# Space characters not displaying in TextView until another character is typed

Tags: ios, textview

I have a couple of UITextViews in a custom UITableViewCell that I have set to right justify text that users enter. However, it currently doesn't display spaces on their own. In other words, if you type "Hello     World" (with five spaces between the two words) the spaces won't appear until the W in world is entered. Not sure what could be causing this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please include a sample of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. You will see this behavior in text fields in most Mac apps as well as iOS text  views. You will see this even when the text is left justified. As you reach the right end of the text area, typing a bunch of spaces doesn't do much until you type some other non-space characters.

When you have right-justified text, the cursor is always at the right side of the text view so you always see this behavior.

Comment: Is there any way to change this behavior then, or is it just inherent in the way the field is constructed?